# F# interactive - how to see all the variables defined in current session

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

In F# interactive, how can I see a list of variables/functions defined in this session? Like a function `whos()` in python or `ls()` in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can probably implement this using .NET Reflection - local variables and functions are defined as static properties/methods of types in a single dynamic assembly. You can get that assembly by calling `GetExecutingAssembly` (in FSI itself) and then browse the types to find all suitable properties.

The following is a reasonably working function for getting local variables:

```
open System.Reflection
open System.Collections.Generic

let getVariables() = 
  let types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
  [ for t in types |> Seq.sortBy (fun t -> t.Name) do
      if t.Name.StartsWith("FSI_") then 
        let flags = BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic |||
                    BindingFlags.Public
        for m in t.GetProperties(flags) do 
          yield m.Name, lazy m.GetValue(null, [||]) ] |> dict
```

Here is an example:

```
> let test1 = "Hello world";;
val test1 : string = "Hello world"

> let test2 = 42;;
val test2 : int = 42

> let vars = getVariables();;
val vars : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,Lazy<obj>>

> vars.["test1"].Value;;
val it : obj = "Hello world"

> vars.["test2"].Value;;
val it : obj = 42
```

The function returns "lazy" value back (because this was the simplest way to write it without reading values of *all* variables in advance which would be slow), so you need to use the `Value` property. Also note that you get `object` back - because there is no way the F# type system could know the type - you'll have to use it dynamically. You can get all names just by iterating over `vars`...

Comment: when I run the cide above, I got a lot of `it` in vars: `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo] it`, what's this and how to filter this out? thanks

Comment: Yes, "it" is automatically generated by F# Interactive (you can see that `it` is also printed in the output - and you can use that variable to get the last result). You can either filter them or just take the last one...

Comment: Wow Thomas, you're a freaking genius. I'm learning F# from you and Jon's book by the way, and I love it :) Great work. Any plans for another book? If you do, stick with Manning, they're a great publisher (at least from my perspective).

Comment: Very useful, but it would be better to yeid `m.Name , (fun () -> m.GetValue(null, [||]))` instead of `m.Name, lazy m.GetValue(null, [||])`.. you’d replace `vars.[“test1”].Value` with `vars.[“test1”]()` and get support for mutable objects because the functor evaluates each time.

Comment: @TomasPetricek This method seems to be not working with the latest (either FSharp.Compiler.Service or net6.0). Any ideas/suggestions? The method was effectively engaged for a while...

Answer (score 8):

I'm developing [FsEye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/), which uses a modified version of @Tomas' technique (filters out unit and function valued vars and only takes the latest `it` var) to grab all FSI session variables upon each submission and displays them visually in a tree so that you can drill down into their object graphs.

You can see my modified version [here](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/Fsi/SessionQueries.fs).

Comment: haha I was thinking of doing something similar, looks like this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll give it a try, awesome work from the look of it!

Comment: Good to hear! It started off as just a little personal tool but then began coming together nicely and I realized a lot of other folks were probably looking for the same kind of thing so I polished it off and released it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in FSI at this stage.

Comment: even no way to write a customized function for this?